# How to separate a line into an array with white space in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I can't figure out why my script is not displaying the string separated by white space.

This is my code:

```
While read -r row
do

   line = ($row)
   for word in $line
   do 
       echo ${word[0]}
   done
done < $1
```

say the line is "add $s0 $s0 $t1"

```
 i want the output to be "add"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
While read -r row
```

This will try to run a command called `While`, you'll probably get an error for that. The shell keyword is `while`.

```
do    
   line = ($row)
```

This will try to run a command called `line`, which is a program from GNU coreutils (`line - read one line`), but probably not what you want. Assignments in the shell must *not* have whitespace around the equal sign.

If that assignment worked, it would make an array called `line`.

```
   for word in $line
```

Referencing the array just by name expands to the first item of it, so the loop is useless here.

```
   do 
       echo ${word[0]}
```

And here, indexing is not very useful since `word` is going to be a single value, not an array.

I suspect what you want is this:

```
while read -r row ; do 
    words=($row);
    echo "${words[0]}"
done
```

Though if `$row` contains glob characters like `*`, they'll be expanded to matching filenames.

This would be better:

```
read -r -a words
echo "${words[0]}"
```

or simply

```
read -r line
echo "${line%% *}"     # remove everything after the first space
```

Answer (score 0):

This work fine :

```
while read -r row
do
  echo $row | awk '{print $1}'
done
```

`while read -r row` ask for user input and store it in `row` variable, `awk '{print $1}'` display only first word of user input.

Comment: no i'm not taking input from user, the lines come from another file. the file is the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want each token on a seperate line? Why not just use `sed`?

```
$ echo "1 2 3 hi" | sed -r 's/[ \t]+/\n/g'
1
2
3
hi
```

If you want the first word of each line, then:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 hi" | sed -r 's/^([^ \t]+).+/\1/'
1
```

If its a file, then remove "echo ... | " and just give the filename as a parameter to sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^ \t]+).+/\1/' file.txt
```